LED blinking in parallel circuit
I have build simple circuit which have 2 LEDs and 2 resistors. The total power for circuit 1 = 0.38 W. Current 7.92 mA. I used two resistors, 4.7 kΩ and 1.6 kΩ. Total resistance for resistor is 1.02 kΩ. The problem is the circuit is blinking for LED. The Vf for LED is around 21 V.
For circuit 2, I used only one resistor 1.1 kΩ while used still same circuit. I don't put resistor for R2 at circuit 2 since I parallel the resistor. But, the LED is not blinking when used only one resistor.
So my question is: why I have different feedback circuit while actually used the same circuit?


What about reading the datasheet of the used LEDs very carefully?

It's the same circuit, however you are likely exceeding the rating of the blinking LED. Here is a typical blinking LED and the device is only rated for 14V absolute maximum.
So you could permanently damage the IC chip by putting so much voltage across it when it attempts to turn off.
You could probably get this to work (assuming two blinking LEDs) by paralleling each LED with a suitable Zener diode (perhaps 10V or 12V, depending on the LED specifications). Retaining the series resistor, of course. The resistor might have to be a watt or two rating.
If one LED is blinking and one is not, then put the two LEDs in series and put a Zener diode across the series pair (retaining the series resistor). The resistor would have to be more like a 2W resistor.

Ok. Noted. thanks for suggestion. Really help
